# c++ win32 checkbox list - multiple selection

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, multiple-select

i would like to add a list of check boxes to my win32 application, because i need a control element with multiple selection. I've searched the msdn docs and found exactly what i need in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407.aspx. But i can't find any code related to it. Is this a special control element? Or is this just a list view filled with check boxes? Or is this a special style for the combo box control? Would appreciate if someone could provide an example or provide a link to the documentation of the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That screenshot is a ListView control with `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES`.

The documented you linked to is UI guidance, not programming documentation. It's talking about UI design, not programmatic control names.

Comment: Raymond, so nice to see you spending time on StackOverflow. I've gotten much insight and enjoyment from your blog over the years. One thing, don't you think that a guide to which UI to choose without at least a pointer to how to achieve the UI is slightly suboptimal?

Comment: @mark such guidance would swamp the real message

Comment: As David said, the purpose of the UI guidance is to describe which types of UI are suitable for which situations. It is not trying to dictate engineering choices. You might want to use a ListView control, or you might decide to use a custom-draw list box, or you might want to use a WPF control. It's your choice as a programmer to choose the control that works best for your program. (In other words, its target audience is UI designers, not UI programmers.)

Comment: @David: I don't think that a "Further Reading" link at the end of each Paragraph would "swamp" any information. IN contradiction such links are VERY useful as you can see in this post. microsoft.com oftenly can merely be used without google search.

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be a built-in capability to the standard LISTBOX control, or there would be a `LBS_xxx` style constant to enable it.

MFC provides a class [`CCheckListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d58s8sak.aspx) to do this.

Comment: i'm not using MFC. i guess i'm on my own on this one.. What would be an alternative? List view populated with checkboxes?

Comment: The way MFC does it is to make it owner draw and draw the checkbox next to the label, then handle the click in the checkbox area.